# Getting issue with java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I'm running a maven dependency build where error generalizes with

> Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.2:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project services-ws: Execution generate-sources of goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:3.2.2:wsdl2java failed: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This class does not support JDK1.5

Already tried to update cxf version in pom.xml as per my code structure with 
`<artifact.cxf.version>3.2.2</artifact.cxf.version>`

Tried every possible indentation which i can find but still is a failure.
Any possible iterations i can try is welcome to add.

plugin in pom

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${artifact.cxf.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>generate-sources</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <sourceRoot>${src.generated.dir}/cxf</sourceRoot>
                            <defaultOptions>
                                <noAddressBinding>true</noAddressBinding>
                                <faultSerialVersionUID>3105839350746982386</faultSerialVersionUID>
                            </defaultOptions>
                            <wsdlOptions>
                                <wsdlOption>
                                    <wsdl>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/CorrelationWS.wsdl</wsdl>
                                    <wsdlLocation>classpath:resources/wsdl/CorrelationWS.wsdl</wsdlLocation>
                                    <extraargs>
                                        <extraarg>-verbose</extraarg>
                                    </extraargs>
                                </wsdlOption>
                            </wsdlOptions>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
                        <version>${xerces.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
```

Comment: What version of the jdk are you using? Are you setting the [`target` java version in maven](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/set-compiler-source-and-target.html)?

Comment: not on the sub-module pom, but in parent pom, it is as:
<java.source>1.8</java.source>
        <java.target>1.8</java.target>